# Multiple Firefox Icons

Tags: macos, firefox

I am going mad with multiple Firefox profiles. They all show the same icon! How can I use multiple icons?

More importantly, how can I change the name in the alt-tab so that it doesn't say "Firefox" for both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By simply making a copy of the Firefox.app, I have another one with another name. Then I replaced the firefox.icns file in the package, and the icon is different.

Also checkout [this link](http://spf13.com/feature/managing-firefox-profiles-os-x).

Answer (score 4):

You can use [CCK Wizard](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/2553), a Firefox add-on that allows you to customize the titlebar (and many other things else).

Install CCK Wizard in all your profiles, and change the titlebar so that it identifies each profile the way you want.

[image]

Comment: But that didn't do what I want, though it's interesting. It does not change the icon (on OSX) nor the name of the executable.